# i can't send E-mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

this my first participation in this forum,
i hope that you can help me ...!

the problem is i can't send e-mails using PHPmailer

Code :

```
class Controller_Mail extends Controller_Template{
protected $oMailer;

public function __construct()
{

    $this->oMailer = new PHPMailer(true);
}

//Envoyer Password Oublie à un candidat  
public function EnvoyerPasswordOublie(Class_Candidat $objCandidat){
    try {

        $nom                 = $objCandidat->getNomPrenom() ;
        $password            = $objCandidat->getPassword() ;
        //$toMailCandidat      = $objCandidat->getMail() ;
        $toMailCandidat      = "amaljob@gmail.com" ;
        $subject             = "Mot de passe oublié !" ;    
        $message             = "Cher (e) <b>".html($nom)."</b>,<br/> <br/> 
                                Suite à votre demande, veuillez trouver ci-dessous votre identifiant et votre mot de passe, vous permettant d'accéder à votre espace :<br/><br/>
                                Email : ".html($toMailCandidat)."<br/>
                                Mot de passe : ".$password."<br/><br/>
                                Cordialement,,<br/><br/>
                                L’Equipe ".ABREV ;
        //$message             = templateStringCandidat($message) ;
        $message             = "message" ;

        $this->oMailer->IsSMTP();
        $this->oMailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $this->oMailer->SMTPDebug  = 2;
        $this->oMailer->Port       = 485;
        $this->oMailer->FromName   = ABREV;
        $this->oMailer->From       = MailsFrom;
        $this->oMailer->AddAddress($toMailCandidat);
        $this->oMailer->AddAddress(MailNotifications);
        $this->oMailer->AddReplyTo(MailsFrom,ABREV);
        $this->oMailer->Subject    = $subject;
        $this->oMailer->MsgHTML($message);
        $this->oMailer->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML 




        if(!$this->oMailer->Send()) {
            return 'erreur : '.$this->oMailer->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

}

and result is False

NB : i already configured SMTP authontification in PHPMailer Class

for information, my website is DEMO and i put it in a subdirectory (www.domain.com/subdirectory)

Comment: and what is in the `Send()` function ?

Comment: @Pogrindis `...->Send();` is a built-in _PHPMailer_ function. It shouldn't need modifying.

Comment: $this->oMailer = new PHPMailer(); should be the first line.

Comment: Could you provide some more details about your environment such as are you running on Windows or Linux (IIS, Apache, Nginx, etc...)? Is this your own server, shared hosting, VPS, or dedicated server? Have you configured a default mail server environment?...

Comment: Whats `$this->oMailer->ErrorInfo` say?

Comment: Why you dont use outlook to do this? You need to use $this->oMailer->Send() out of if command.

Comment: You should not be modifying the class - if you want to change how it works, preset some properties (like your username and password), subclass it. It also looks like you have based your code on an old example - make sure you [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and look in the examples folder. You don't need to call `isHTML` if you call `msgHTML`. You're also calling both `isMail` and `isSMTP` - make your mind up!

Comment: @War10ck I have not modified PHPMailer function, i just add SMTP authentification (HOST : USER : PAST)

i have a windows server (Plesk),
configuration of mail server is good because it's work for other websites

Comment: @El3phanten : $this->oMailer = new PHPMailer(); already existe 
this is all my function:

look to my post i modified the code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  ErrorInfo is empty :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$this->oMailer->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL; //SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL=4`

this value outputs much more infomation about possible error

Comment: thank you for you answar,
i tried to use `$this->oMailer->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL;`
then i got `500 Internal Server Error` 

what's weird is that I use phpmailer with the same configuration for another websites, and that work well!

the only difference is that the other websites in subdomains (http://subdomain.domain.com)

and this site (DEMO) in a subdirectory (http://domaine.net/subdirectory)

could this be the problem?!

Comment: also i tried this [exemple](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) but result is always false and `ErrorInfo` is empty

Comment: I wrote code for latest versions with lowlevel debuging, it must work - try to update your version.
subdomain or subfolder can't create that problem